# How to save java object in postgres jsonb column

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-webflux, r2dbc

Here is my code:
I need to save java object value as jsonb in database (r2dbc).

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table("scoring")
public class ScoringModel extends BaseModel {

    @Column("client_id")
    @SerializedName(value = "clientId", alternate = {"client_id"})
    private String clientId;
    //othres
    @Column("languages")
    @SerializedName(value = "languages", alternate = {"languages"})
    private String languages;

    @SerializedName(value = "response", alternate = {"response"})
    //Need to save as JsonB
    private Object response;
}
```

Please help me resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `ReadingConverter` and `WritingConverter` and then register them in `R2dbcCustomConversions` in configuration.

```java
@Bean
public R2dbcCustomConversions myConverters(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
var dialect = DialectResolver.getDialect(connectionFactory);
    var converters = List.of(…);
    return R2dbcCustomConversions.of(dialect, converters);
}
```

Converters itself should produce JSONs.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Postgres, there are two approaches you can use to map to Postgres JSON/JSONB fields.

1. use Postgres R2dbc `Json` type directly in Java entity class.
2. use any Java type and convert it between `Json` via registering custom converters.

The first one is simple and stupid.

1. Declare a `json` db type field, eg.

   ```
   metadata   JSON         default '{}'
   ```
2. Declare the `Json` type field in your entity class.

   ```java
   class Post{
        @Column("metadata")
        private Json metadata;
   }
   ```

For the second the solution, similarly

1. Declare `json`/`jsonb` db type in the [schema.sql](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/pg-json/src/main/resources/schema.sql#L7).
2. Declare the field type as your custom type.eg.

   ```java
   class Post{
        @Column("statistics")
        private Statistics statistics;


       record Statistics(
            Integer viewed,
            Integer bookmarked
       ) {}
   }
   ```
3. Declare a `R2dbcCustomConversions` bean.

   ```java
    @Configuration
    class DataR2dbcConfig {
        @Bean
        R2dbcCustomConversions r2dbcCustomConversions(ConnectionFactory factory, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            R2dbcDialect dialect = DialectResolver.getDialect(factory);
            return R2dbcCustomConversions
                    .of(
                            dialect,
                            List.of(
                                    new JsonToStatisticsConverter(objectMapper),
                                    new StatisticsToJsonConverter(objectMapper)
                            )
                    );
        }

    }

    @ReadingConverter
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    class JsonToStatisticsConverter implements Converter<Json, Post.Statistics> {
        private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public Post.Statistics convert(Json source) {
            return objectMapper.readValue(source.asString(), Post.Statistics.class);
        }
    }

    @WritingConverter
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    class StatisticsToJsonConverter implements Converter<Post.Statistics, Json> {
        private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public Json convert(Post.Statistics source) {
            return Json.of(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(source));
        }
    }
   ```

The example codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/tree/master/pg-json).

Finally verify it with a [`@DataR2dbcTest` test](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/pg-json/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostRepositoryTest.java).

```java
@Test
public void testInsertAndQuery() {
        var data = Post.builder()
                .title("test title")
                .content("content of test")
                .metadata(Json.of("{\"tags\":[\"spring\",\"r2dbc\"]}"))
                .statistics(new Post.Statistics(1000, 200))
                .build();
        this.template.insert(data)
                .thenMany(
                        this.posts.findByTitleContains("test%")
                )
                .log()
                .as(StepVerifier::create)
                .consumeNextWith(p -> {
                            log.info("saved post: {}", p);
                            assertThat(p.getTitle()).isEqualTo("test title");
                        }
                )
                .verifyComplete();

}
```